# PHP - check if somethings match with the string

Tags: php

I have a string with like 10 informations, but I only need one of them, and thats the rank. I already tried to put it in another string, but its not working with my code so far as I want it to.

My current code looks like this:

```
if (strpos($rank, 'Platin I') !== false) {
   echo 'Platin I';
} elseif (strpos($rank, 'Platin II') !== false) {
   echo 'Platin II';
}
```

If the $rank is `Platin II`, then my code give out `Platin I`.
How can I check if the actual rank is matched?

Thats in between the string: `Division I Platin II Division`

Comment: You should check for `Platin II` first then `Platin I`.

Comment: If a string contains `foobar`, it also contains `foo`. You always need to check the longer string first.

Comment: Okay, yeah that makes sense... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string contains `Platin II`, it also contains `Platin I`, so you need to match the longer string first.

Another solution is to use a regular expression, then you can match word boundaries, so you don't match partial words.

```
if (preg_match('/\bPlatin I\b/', $rank)) {
    echo 'Platin I';
} elseif (preg_match('/\bPlatin II\b/', $rank)) {
    echo 'Platin II';
}
```